# Коммерческий сайт

Tags: оптимизация-сайтов, юридические-аспекты, it-бизнес

Здравствуйте.

Разрабатываю сайт, сам. Опыта мало, но учусь.
Хочу обратиться в "веб студию" для доработки.

Вопрос: Стоит ли доверять "Свой" код и идею кому-то?

Что если также использовать разработку как Дипломный проект в ВУЗЕ?
Не предъявит ли ВУЗ что диплом собственность ВУЗа?

Comment: Договор с ВУЗ-ом читали?

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что он не относится к программированию.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Лучше доделывай сам, а то что не сможешь пиши на форум, можешь писать мне в скайп node_xaker. Студия вряд ли утащит идею, но денежку утащит приличную. Насчет ВУЗа, там не должно быть проблем. Также в дипломе не столько важна программа как  ее описание

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ!В догонку хочу поинтересоваться-где я могу купить/заказать эксклюзивные картинки и иконки для своего сайта? Сам не силен

Comment: @Rust, обращайтесь. Все когда-то начинали ;-)